# Error Dialog Displayed When F1 Pressed In Combobox

Tags: vb6, dialog

I have a combobox (cboURL) on a User Control whose Style property is set to '0 - Dropdown Combo'. When the combobox has focus and F1 is pressed, a dialog window is displayed containing the error text 'This program cannot display the webpage'.

The required behaviour is that the F1 keypress is sent to UserControl_KeyDown so that F1 can be suppressed (as it is for all other controls on the UserControl):

```
Private Sub UserControl_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyF1 Then KeyCode = 0
End Sub
```

The UserControl's KeyPreview property is set to True.

None of the event handlers cboURL_KeyDown(), cboURL_KeyUp(), cboURL_KeyPress(), UserControl_KeyDown(), UserControl_KeyUp() or UserControl_KeyPress() are called when F1 is pressed in cboURL. Nor are the Form_KeyDown(), Form_KeyPress() or Form_KeyUp() event handlers called in the form in which the User Control is embedded.

If cboURL's Style property is set to '2 - Dropdown List', then when F1 is pressed UserControl_KeyDown *is* called. I can't use that setting, however, because I need to be able to input text which is not in the list of dropdown options.

A .chm help file for this application does exist (generated by hhc.exe), but it is not a standalone help file. Double-clicking on it from Windows Exporer gives the same error dialog as described above, for example. The help file contains popup help text accessed using the WhatsThisHelpID property of the controls.

Can anyone suggest a fix or a workaround for this issue please?

Comment: It sounds like it is trying to load the help file for your program, which obviously doesn't exist. F1 is the default key for loading help files. Have you tried checking your form's `KeyDown/KeyPress` event to see if that is being fired?

Comment: Try setting `KeyPreview = True` on the containing form, `KeyDown` event handler goes there. Works here.

Comment: Alfie, thank you for your reply. I have added more information in response to your questions.

Comment: wqw - thank you. That has fixed (or worked around!) the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref. comment from wqw:
"Try setting KeyPreview = True on the containing form, KeyDown event handler goes there. Works here."

This worked fine.